# How to get the current url with php?

Tags: javascript, php

Here is a problem with `"https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` when I using this code in a php file, which I called from a JS (with fetch or XMLHttpRequest), the output will be the the current url of this .php file!

Example I call PHP in JS (on my wordpress site):

```
    const item = document.querySelector('.item');
    fetch('path/wp-content/themes/current_theme_directory/called.php')
   .then(res => res.text())
   .then(responseText => item.innerHTML = responseText);
```

And my called.php file contain this code:

```
   $current_url = "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
   echo $current_url;
```

My responseText in my JS this: path/wp-content/themes/current_theme_directory/called.php

In this situation how can I get the real current url, what shows my browser also?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to get. You don't mean `window.location.href`?

Comment: Make sure the url path in -     fetch('path/wp-content/themes/current_theme_directory/called.php')
 - is correct.

Comment: If you're JS is inside a PHP file, you can just set the current url there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` will have the url that loaded the PHP, but keep in mind that info is easily edited by a crafty user.

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect! This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

you can get the current url using javascript, it's in a variable called `window.location.href`

`console.log(window.location.href);` will log the current `url` in the console.